# Unexpected output for keras ReLU layer

Tags: python, keras, threshold, relu

In the keras documentation, the function `keras.activations.relu(x, alpha=0.0, max_value=None, threshold=0.0)` is defined as:

```
f(x) = max_value for x >= max_value,
f(x) = x for threshold <= x < max_value,
f(x) = alpha * (x - threshold) otherwise.
```

I did a small test with `alpha=0.01`, `threshold=5.0` and `max_value=100.0` and for `x=5.0` the output I get is `f(x)=0.0`.

If I am not mistaken, since `x == threshold`, I should get `f(x)=x=5.0`.

Can anyone explain please?

Thanks,

- Julien

Comment: Please edit your question, rather than posting details as answers. Things would be much clearer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The documentation in the source code is wrong. (And you should be moving to `tf.keras` instead of `keras`). It should be,

```
f(x) = max_value for x >= max_value,
--> f(x) = x for threshold < x < max_value,
f(x) = alpha * (x - threshold) otherwise.
```

So when your `x` == `threshold` it goes to the third case which has a `0` in it (i.e. `x - threshold`). This is why you get `0`.

If you need the behavior documented [this line](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/7a39b6c62d43c25472b2c2476bd2a8983ae4f682/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py#L3278) needs to change as,

`x = x * tf.cast(tf.greater_equal(x, threshold), floatx())`

Comment: I was not able to find the ReLU code in tensorflow by myself...
Thanks a lot!!